# Как заменить CONNECT BY на WITH

Tags: sql, oracle, iso

И снова здравствуйте. Есть таблица:

```
create table test_table (
id integer not null,
name char(1) not null,
parent_id integer,
sum integer not null);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(1, 'A', null, 300);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(11, 'B', 1, 2340);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(111, 'C', 11, 3200);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(22, 'D', 1, 7540);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(2, 'E', null, 6300);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(3, 'F', 2, 8600);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(101, 'G', 3, 3800);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(102, 'H', 3, 9700);
```

А есть код:

```
SELECT lpad(' ', 3*level)||name as Tree   
FROM test_table A
START WITH parent_id is null
CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id;
```

Как сделать то же самое без использования `CONNECT BY` (через `WITH`)?

Итак, я нашел вариант применения с использованием `WITH`([здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/43955/)), да вот только он не работает - показывает на название CTE и говорит, мол отсутствует ключевое слово:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
  Rec (id, parent_id, name)
  AS (
    SELECT id, parent_id, name FROM test_table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Rec.id, Rec.parent_id, Rec.name
      FROM Rec, test_table
      WHERE Rec.id = test_table.parent_id
  )
SELECT * FROM Rec 
WHERE parent_id is null;
```

Comment: А Вы сами как уже пробовали?

Comment: Ну на такие вопросы гугл отлично отвечает https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:53139879276132  даже в текст вчитываться не надо. примеры кода смотрите и все

Comment: Видимо, неправильно искал)

Comment: Пожалуй, правильная терминология решает. я спросил гугл "oracle recursive cte"

Comment: но отступы с использованием level требуют connect by

Comment: @Mike Это нужно как-то через rownumber обыгрывать level? Мне просто не совсем понятна логика присвоения того или иного значения столбцу level. Он ищет корневой элемент, присваивает ему 1, идет дальше по ветке, встречает дочерний и присваивает ему 2, так?

Comment: Да, так. В CTE в первй части делаем просто `1 as lvl` в рекурсивной части на этом месте пишем `lvl+1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Приведу пример, как бы я переписал ваш запрос для MS SQL (там как раз CONNECT нет, есть только recursive CTE). Только функцию для умножения пробелов в начале менять не стал - в MS SQL она другая. Попробуйте, подойдет ли вам такой вариант:

```
with rec (id, parent_id, name, lvl)
as (
select  id, parent_id, name, 0
from    test_table
where   parent_id is null
union all
select tt.id, tt.parent_id, tt.name, rec.lvl + 1
from    test_table tt
        inner join rec
                on tt.parent_id = rec.id
)
SELECT lpad(' ', 3*lvl)||name as Tree
from    rec
```

Comment: К сожалению. Если мы добавим level в список столбцов для CTE, Oracle не будет знать, откуда его искать, т.к. в моей таблице его нет, CONNECT BY тоже. Стало быть, нужно его убирать. Убрал. дальше строчка select  id, parent_id, name, 0 as level - ошибка "Ключевое слово FROM найдено не там, где ожидалось. Ладно, меняем level на lvl во всех местах, тогда выдается еще одна ошибка "Число имен столбцов фразы WITH не соответствует числу элементов в списке выбора", добавляем lvl в выборку столбцов CTE - "Обнаружен цикл при выполнении рекурсивного запроса" Все, круг замкнулся)

Comment: @daydark Я проверил этот запрос. если в рекурсивной части к столбцам добавить что они из таблицы `tt` и по всему запросу слово level (зарезервированное в Oracle для connect by) заменить например на lvl - то все отлично работает

Comment: Вот блин. Знал бы я еще, что эта tt существует

Comment: @daydark ну так ее же сами так и назвали вот этим `from    test_table tt`

Comment: @daydark, да, моя ошибка, tt - это алиас к вашей же таблице для удобства написания. 
Mike, спасибо за правку.